# smooth.spline(): fitted model does not match user-specified degree of freedom

Tags: r, regression, spline, smoothing

Here is the code I ran

```
fun <- function(x) {1 + 3*sin(4*pi*x-pi)}
set.seed(1)
num.samples <- 1000
x <- runif(num.samples)
y <- fun(x) + rnorm(num.samples) * 1.5
fit <- smooth.spline(x, y, all.knots=TRUE, df=3)
```

Despite `df=3`, when I checked the fitted model, the output was

```
Call:
smooth.spline(x = x, y = y, df = 3, all.knots = TRUE)
Smoothing Parameter  spar= 1.499954  lambda= 0.002508571 (26 iterations)
Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 9.86422
```

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the degrees of freedom you provide is a goal that the algorithm tries to optimize towards (among other criteria) and that is simply as close as the algorithm could get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that from R-3.4.0 (2017-04-21), `smooth.spline` can accept direct specification of `λ` by a newly added argument `lambda`. But it will still be converted to the internal one `spar` during estimation. So the following answer is not affected.

---

**Smoothing parameter `λ` / `spar` lies in the centre of smoothness control**

Smoothness is controlled by smoothing parameter `λ`.`smooth.spline()` uses an internal smoothing parameter `spar` rather than `λ`:

```
spar = s0 + 0.0601 * log(λ)
```

Such logarithm transform is necessary in order to do unconstrained minimization, like GCV/CV. User can specify `spar` to indirectly specify `λ`. When `spar` grows linearly, `λ` will grow exponentially. Thus there is rarely the need for using large `spar` value.

The degree of freedom `df`, is also defined in terms of `λ`:

[image: edf]

where `X` is the model matrix with B-spline basis and `S` is the penalty matrix.

You can have a check on their relationships with your dataset:

```
spar <- seq(1, 2.5, by = 0.1)
a <- sapply(spar, function (spar_i) unlist(smooth.spline(x, y, all.knots=TRUE, spar = spar_i)[c("df","lambda")]))
```

Let's sketch `df ~ spar`, `λ ~ spar` and `log(λ) ~ spar`:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(spar, a[1, ], type = "b", main = "df ~ spar",
     xlab = "spar", ylab = "df")
plot(spar, a[2, ], type = "b", main = "lambda ~ spar",
     xlab = "spar", ylab = "lambda")
plot(spar, log(a[2,]), type = "b", main = "log(lambda) ~ spar",
     xlab = "spar", ylab = "log(lambda)")
```

[image: plot]

Note the radical growth of `λ` with `spar`, the linear relationship between `log(λ)` and `spar`, and the relatively smooth relationship between `df` and `spar`.

---

**`smooth.spline()` fitting iterations for `spar`**

If we manually specify the value of `spar`, like what we did in the `sapply()`, no fitting iterations is done for selecting `spar`; otherwise `smooth.spline()` needs iterate through a number of `spar` values. If we

- specify `cv = TRUE / FALSE`, fitting iterations aims to minimize CV/GCV score;
- specify `df = mydf`, fitting iterations aims to minimize `(df(spar) - mydf) ^ 2`.

Minimizing GCV is easy to follow. We don't care about the GCV score, but care the corresponding `spar`. On the contrary, when minimizing `(df(spar) - mydf)^2`, we often care about the `df` value at the end of iteration rather than `spar`! But bearing in mind that this is an minimization problem, we are never guaranteed that the final `df` matches our target value `mydf`.

---

**Why you put `df = 3`, but get `df = 9.864?`**

The end of iteration, could either implies hitting a minimum, or reaching searching boundary, or reaching maximum number of iterations.

We are far from maximum iterations limit (default 500); yet we do not hit the minimum. Well, we might reach the boundary.

Do not focus on `df`, think about `spar`.

```
smooth.spline(x, y, all.knots=TRUE, df=3)$spar   # 1.4999
```

According to `?smooth.spline`, by default, `smooth.spline()` searches `spar` between `[-1.5, 1.5]`. I.e., when you put `df = 3`, minimization terminates at the searching boundary, rather than hitting `df = 3`.

Have a look at our graph of the relationship between `df` and `spar`, again. From the figure, it looks like that we need some `spar` value near 2 in order to result in `df = 3`.

Let's use `control.spar` argument:

```
fit <- smooth.spline(x, y, all.knots=TRUE, df=3, control.spar = list(high = 2.5))
# Smoothing Parameter  spar= 1.859066  lambda= 0.9855336 (14 iterations)
# Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 3.000305
```

Now you see, you end up with `df = 3`. And we need a `spar = 1.86`.

---

**A better suggestion: Do not use `all.knots = TRUE`**

Look, you have 1000 data. With `all.knots = TRUE` you will use 1000 parameters. Wishing to end up with `df = 3` implies that 997 out of 1000 parameters are suppressed. Imagine how large a `λ` hence `spar` you need!

Try using penalized regression spline instead. Suppressing 200 parameters to 3 is definitely much easier:

```
fit <- smooth.spline(x, y, nknots = 200, df=3)  ## using 200 knots
# Smoothing Parameter  spar= 1.317883  lambda= 0.9853648 (16 iterations)
# Equivalent Degrees of Freedom (Df): 3.000386
```

Now, you end up with `df = 3` without `spar` control.