# Control the degree of smoothing in my simple kernel smoothing code

Tags: r, regression, smoothing

I need help in customizing the smoothing to my time series data. The code below smooths the data using `sm.regression` and `approx` functions, but the  degree of smoothing is not user controlled, i.e. By changing function parameters I want the ability to control whether the smoothed curve follows the underlying data more closely or less closely.

```
    find.extrema <- function(x)
    {
        if(is.xts(x)) {
            y = as.vector( Cl(x) )
        } else {
            y = x
        }
        n = len(y)
        t = 1:n
        h = h.select(t, y, method = 'cv')
        temp = sm.regression(t, y, h=h, display = 'none')
        mhat = approx(temp$eval.points, temp$estimate, t, method='linear')$y
        #mhat = y #to exactly match underlying data
        return (mhat)
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `sm.regression` from? Why not use one of R's many preexisting smoothing options from `smooth.spline` and `loess` to any GAM you can dream up?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: Thanks, I was running short of time, and have no experience in R.  Thats why I deleted my previous question, edited it to make it as clear as I possibly could with my limited knowledge of R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not many questions regarding the `sm` package. Perhaps it is not widely used nowadays, but I still remember playing with it a lot when doing my MRes degree.

You can't control smoothness because you are using cross-validation for auto-selection of smoothing parameter. Just get rid of the `h.select` line and pass `h` as an argument of your function.

```
find.extrema <- function(x, h = NULL)
{
    if(is.xts(x)) {
        y = as.vector( Cl(x) )
    } else {
        y = x
    }
    n = len(y)
    t = 1:n
    ## if not given, do auto-selection from data
    if (is.null(h)) h = h.select(t, y, method = 'cv')
    temp = sm.regression(t, y, h=h, display = 'none')
    mhat = approx(temp$eval.points, temp$estimate, t, method='linear')$y
    #mhat = y #to exactly match underlying data
    return (mhat)
}
```

The whole point of `sm` package on kernel smoothing and / or kernel density estimation, is the cross-validation part. If you don't utilize it, you can just use `ksmooth` from R base for Nadaraya-Watson kernel estimator. You may read more about it from [Scatter plot kernel smoothing: ksmooth() does not smooth my data at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37952793/4891738). I did made a comparison with `sm.regression` there.