# Is it possible to control the degrees of freedom for the smooth functions in a GAM fit in R, and if so, how?

Tags: r, regression, gam, mgcv

I am using the `mgcv` package in R to fit a GAM to some hydrologic data as follows:

```
d <- GAM_example_data[,1:4]
colnames(d) <- c("month","rain","pump","GWL")             
fitted_GAM <- gam(GWL~s(month) + s(rain) + s(pump), data = d)
plot.gam(fitted_GAM)
```

When I get the plots that are output from `plot.gam`, on the y-axis it tells me the degrees of freedom for each of the smoothing functions, and these are often non-integer values. **I wish to be able to control the degrees of freedom for each of the smooth functions used, is there a way to do this?**

I have seen references to specifying the "knots" and therefore controlling the fit but I am fairly new to the concept of GAMs and I haven't been able to find any clear resources explaining what these are (if they are even related to my problem at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been closely following how you would respond to the other answer. From your reply it appears that know several concepts in GAM well, then I could produce a short answer.

Unfortunately, no. `mgcv` GAM is not doing estimation using backfitting, but performs a joint estimation of smoothing parameters by GCV or REML. So unlike the legacy `gam` package, where you can specify a `df` for each spline term, you can't achieve this in `mgcv`.

The only way to control smoothness **in penalized regression setting**, is to set smoothing parameter `sp`, but its relationship with degree of freedom is not in closed form and you can not foresee it.

The other answer is suggesting you doing a pure regression spline without penalization. By setting a rank `k` and signaling `fx = TRUE`, you always have degree of freedom equal to rank minus one (as a result of centering constraint), which is an integer.

---

Here are some other answers I made on smoothing.

[smooth.spline(): fitted model does not match user-specified degree of freedom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36779660/4891738) explains how setting `df` works in `smooth.spline`. Note that this is the basis of backfitting GAM.

[How to interpret lm() coefficient estimates when using bs() function for splines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37362738/4891738) explains the basis of pure regression spline. Of course, `mgcv` offers a great many spline basis class, not just the B-spline used by `splines::bs`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of parameters in the `gam` documentation to get your head around.

I think the most useful parameter for your case is `k`, the *basis dimension*. Essentially, it sets the upper limit on the degrees of freedom for a smooth using `s`. [Here is some documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/choose.k.html).

So you might run, for example:

```
gam(GWL ~ s(month, k = 4) + ...)
```

Then examine your model using `plot.gam` and `gam.check`. If the diagnostics don't look good, you can adjust `k` up or down until they improve.

EDIT: According to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12223/how-to-tune-smoothing-in-mgcv-gam-model), the `fx = TRUE` argument to `s()` will fit a regression spline with fixed degrees of freedom. k will equal total df and k-1 = edf.

Comment: Thanks for your response, adjusting k to set the maximum degrees of freedom has helped me play with the fit a bit more.

In addition however, for some other verification process I need to be able to replicate the GAM fitting results from a legacy piece of software that I no longer have access to. Do you know if there is a way to directly set what degree of freedom to fit to? Or at least constrain the values to integer values?

Comment: According to this answer, the `fx = TRUE` argument to `s()` will fit a regression spline with fixed degrees of freedom: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12223/how-to-tune-smoothing-in-mgcv-gam-model. I guess k will equal total df and k-1 = edf.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. If you could add your comment to your original answer, and I'll accept it.